# Javascript - Why call method is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, call

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/ta2u2z9a/

```
var o = {
    x: 6
};

function a() {
    this.x = 3;
    this.y = function() {
        alert(this.x)
    }
}

var a1 = new a();
a1.y.call(); //shouldn't it alert 3?

a1.y.call(o) //is alerting 6, correct!
```

Why is the first alert, alerting undefined? shouldn't it alert 3?

Comment: Change a1.y.call() => a1.y.call(a1);

Comment: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 10):

The first argument to `.call()` needs to be the "owner object" of the method:

```
a1.y.call(a1);
```

**What's going on?**

When you call a method "naturally" (e.g. `a1.y()`), the value of `this` is automatically set to the object (e.g. `a1`).

When using the function *not* as a method (e.g. `var x = a1.y;  x();`), the value of `this` is either the global/window object, or `null` (depending on whether you're in "strict mode" or not).

The `.call()` method (it's a method *of the function*) is a way to explicitly set the `this` value, instead of having it automatically assigned.  When using `.call()`, you have to supply the `this` value yourself, as the first argument.

Comment: If you don't pass object you get undefined as this and you will get window object as this if you don't use strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not sent the expected "this" parameter in call() as an argument so this is undefined in that function.

If you are not passing any argument to call() then no need to use it. Simply call the method on the object.