# JavaScript simple call function behavior

Tags: javascript

I want to ask about call function behavior. I get stuck every time when I try to understand `call` function.

Can anybody help me to understand what is going on by suggesting implementation of the `find` method?

```js
Hoge = function (val) {
  this.val = val;
  //console.log("this.val" + this.val);
};

Hoge.prototype.find = function (callback) {
  callback.call(this.val);
};

var h = new Hoge(1);

h.find((o) => { 
  console.log(o);  // expected 1 but undefined
  console.log(o === 1); // expected true but  its false (caz o is undefined)
});
```

Comment: What's the first argument of `call` supposed to be?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295056/javascript-why-call-method-is-not-working-correctly

Comment: @Calculuswhiz thanks . i missed argument . i saw that reference . regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) a `thisArg` argument.  Well, you *are*, but it's value you want passed to the callback.

```js
Hoge = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  //console.log("this.val" + this.val);
};

Hoge.prototype.find = function(callback) {
  // callback.call(this.val);
  callback.call(this, this.val); // call wants a "this" argument
  // callback(this.val); // Could just do this instead
};

var h = new Hoge(1);

h.find((o) => {
  console.log(o); // expected 1 but undefined
  console.log(o === 1); // expected true but  its false (caz o is undefined)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)'s first parameter is the `this` value. To directly invoke a function, just use parentheses.

```
callback(this.val);
```

```js
Hoge = function (val) {
  this.val = val;
};

Hoge.prototype.find = function (callback) {
  callback(this.val);
};

var h = new Hoge(1);

h.find((o) => { 
  console.log(o);
  console.log(o === 1);
});
```

Comment: i was referring wrong document . i got it . thanks for the quick help

Comment: @oshigoto46 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first param in `call` will be the new `this` you want to use. Then onwards are the params you want to pass.

You are basically not making a lot of use `.call` here, and if you simply want to use `o` you can pass `null` and `this.val`.

Even simpler, simply invoke the `callback` function

```js
Hoge = function (val) {
  this.val = val;
  //console.log("this.val" + this.val);
};

Hoge.prototype.find = function (callback) {
  //Both work
  callback.call(null,this.val);
  callback(this.val);
};

var h = new Hoge(1);

h.find((o) => { 
  console.log(o);  // expected 1 but undefined
  console.log(o === 1); // expected true but  its false (caz o is undefined)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help . null or this works for the first argument. i was at a loss. that helps me a lot . regards,